# Using Jenkins Container to build Delphi applications

Tags: docker, delphi, jenkins

I wish to setup Jenkins using Docker to build different projects, some are in Delphi, some in node.js + AngularJS.

For the node.js and Angular, I think it can be done with a Linux container, but for what concerns the Delphi I think I have to use a Windows container or an agent build on windows container.

I've tried googling around but I've not found any docker container build on windows and Jenkins agent.

Anyone has got a similar need and found a clean and easy way to set up such an enviorment?

Thanks

Comment: As per my research you will need a Windows Slave for building Delphi. Of course you could use a Windows Docker Container, but you still need a Windows Docker Host Machine underneath.

Comment: is there a official container or should I have to create a custom one?

Comment: There is no official image, but you could check out some of these:
https://hub.docker.com/search?q=delphi&type=image&operating_system=windows

I hope i was able to help!